# Starting with Doctrine. Which version is good to?

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I'm using Zend Framework and I feel that I need a good ORM to work with. I don't know much of Zend Framework, I just know how to do the basics. I expect to work together with both Doctrine and Zend Framework

But to sget started, I'm going to try a simple Doctrine project (no ZF) to get used to the application. Then I'll try to integrate it in ZF

Which version of Doctrine do I start learning? Does Doctrine have a good integration with ZF?

Besides,
Is there any recent site for Doctrine learning? I just can't find the sandbox version to follow the Doctrine documentation. If anyone knows of any tutorial on how to get started with doctrine only first, please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done projects with zend framework and doctrine. They play pretty nice together.

I followed [this tutorial](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine) and it worked well.

But honestly I don't use doctrine on anything but the largest sites. I've switched over to [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/). Zero configuration autodiscovery, and the ability to freeze data models when you are done for maximum performance.

You should really try it out, it is so simple its stupid. It is really one of the best ORM's ive ever used. EVER. Try it.

Comment: +1 although doctrine is widely accepted , but i'd like to see RedBean , could you please write a blogpost about your experience with RedBean :)

Comment: Never heard of RedBean until now. The demo video was impressive and very cool, but I was turned off by the silly method names (`dispense`, `store`)...

Answer (score 0):

I am personally using Doctrine 1.2

and i followed the [Zendcasts.com](http://www.zendcasts.com/?s=doctrine) "more than 5 casts about doctrine" & same Byron's [tuts](http://ruben.savanne.be/articles/integrating-zend-framework-and-doctrine)

both of them is good

Update : 
 1- http://www.zendcasts.com/deep-integration-between-zend-and-doctrine-1-2/2010/01/ has the sample code

2- http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/download/1.2.3  has the doctrine framework if you need to download it alone

Comment: do you know where can i find the doctrine sandbox to download?

Answer (score 0):

I've found Doctrine2 reasonable stable, although it's still in beta. It seems most of the other PHP 'ORM' libraries (Doctrine 1.2 included) are Active Record, while Doctrine2 is a Data Mapper. In my opinion, you can put together a relatively [simple Active Record using Zend's native `Db_Table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821450/can-a-simple-model-just-extend-zend-db-row-essentially-active-record), so that makes Doctrine 1.2 less appealing (at least to me).

I've used this answer about [integrating Doctrine2 and Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325058/integrating-zf-doctrine2-where-do-i-put-my-models-entities-proxy-classes/3580652#3580652).

I [agree with Byron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169653/starting-with-doctrine-which-version-is-good-to/4169695#4169695), and have only used Doctrine2 on select projects.

*[As an aside, I've noticed RedBean in the past, and have wanted to try it - from what I've seen it's certainly worth taking a look.]*

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 2 is in beta and requires PHP5.3 as it fully utilizes Namespaces. If you cannot use PHP5.3 in your project, you cannot use Doctrine 2.

Apart from that, there has been a number of architectural changes in Doctrine 2 that make it much more attractive than Doctrine < 2, mainly

- using DataMapper instead of ActiveRecord
- promotes DI over static calls
- faster and less memory-intensive
- revolves around Entities and DDD
- uses "Annotations"

See

- http://architects.dzone.com/articles/doctrine-1-doctrine-2
- http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/doctrine-2-not-the-same-old-php-orm