# Can't load Doctrine2 Configuration class in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create `Configuration`:

`$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;`

Although I can see this class using `Open declaration` in Zend Studio running it in browser results in:

`Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Configuration' not found in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\MyProject\library\Custom\Entitymanager.php on line 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure doctrine is in the include path and you have autoloadernamespaces[] = "Doctrine" in application.ini file

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine has a nice autoloader:

```
require '/path/to/libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', '/path/to/libraries');
$classLoader->register(); // register on SPL autoload stack
```

Also see the similar questions:

- [Integrating ZF/Doctrine2: Where do i put my Models/Entities & Proxy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325058/integrating-zf-doctrine2-where-do-i-put-my-models-entities-proxy-classes)
- [ZF + Doctrine 2 on SO](/search?q=[doctrine2]+[zend-framework])